# Hero Image overlapping with Hamburger menu made from pure HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

What my problem is that i have followed a tutorial on how to make a hamburger menu with just CSS & HTML. I later made a hero image background to go on my website. However, when in mobile view to click the hamburger menu, the entire content of the HERO background covers the part of the hamburger menu that comes in to the HERO background area, thus making the hamburger menu functionally useless. I've tried looking for other solutions, and ive found two problems which is the same as mine, but not completely, and has not worked in solving the problem.

Here is the HTML Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>test</title>

  <!-- General Stylesheets -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/general_index.css">


  <!-- Stylesheet for mobile users -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(hover: none)" href="css/mobile_nav.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(hover: none)" href="css/mobile_index_general.css">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" meida="(hover: none)" href="css/test.css"> -->


  <!-- Stylesheet for desktop users -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(hover: hover)" href="css/desktop_nav.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(hover: hover)" href="css/desktop_index_general.css">
  <style>
    #errorcode {
      color: red;
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    #success {
      color: green;
    }

    header {
      height: 5em;
      background-color: #b8241c;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="hamburger-menu navlinks">
        <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
        <label class="menu__btn" for="menu__toggle">
          <span></span>
        </label>

        <ul class="menu__box">
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
<main>

  <h1 class="mainTitle">Why Our Country Needs You!</h1>


  <div class="hero-image">
    <di class="hero-container">
      <h1><span>Freedom</span></h1>
      <span class="des"> TEST TEXT // EVEN MORE TEST</span>
      <a href="" class="btn">Help now!</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="titleOne"><h2>We are under a massive XXX XXX!</h2></div>
    <div class="titleTwo"><h2>The XXX is removing our only playing card!</h2></div>
    <div class="DescOne"><p>this is just some descriptive text for title 1 
    this is just some descriptive text for title 1 this is just some descriptive text for title 1
    this is just some descriptive text for title 1 this is just some descriptive text for title 1
    this is just some descriptive text for title 1 this is just some descriptive text for title 1
    this is just some descriptive text for title 1 this is just some descriptive text for title 1
    this is just some descriptive text for title 1 this is just some descriptive text for title 1
    this is just some descriptive text for title 1 this is just some descriptive text for title 1
    this is just some descriptive text for title 1 this is just some descriptive text for title 1
    </p></div>
    <div class="Desc2"><p>this is just some descriptive text for title 2
    this is just some descriptive text for title 2 this is just some descriptive text for title 2
    this is just some descriptive text for title 2 this is just some descriptive text for title 2
    this is just some descriptive text for title 2 this is just some descriptive text for title 2
    this is just some descriptive text for title 2 this is just some descriptive text for title 2
    this is just some descriptive text for title 2 this is just some descriptive text for title 2
    this is just some descriptive text for title 2 this is just some descriptive text for title 2
    this is just some descriptive text for title 2 this is just some descriptive text for title 2
    this is just some descriptive text for title 2 this is just some descriptive text for title 2
    </p></div>
  </div>

</main>
 <footer>

</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS for the hamburger menu(hamburger menu and hero image is seperate files).

```css
#menu__toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}
#menu__toggle:checked + .menu__btn > span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#menu__toggle:checked + .menu__btn > span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
#menu__toggle:checked + .menu__btn > span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
#menu__toggle:checked ~ .menu__box {
  left: 0 !important;
}
.menu__btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu__btn > span,
.menu__btn > span::before,
.menu__btn > span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}
.menu__btn > span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}
.menu__btn > span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}
.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transition-duration: .25s;
}
.menu__item {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}
.menu__item:hover {
  background-color: #CFD8DC;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Here is the CSS for the HERO background:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.hero-image {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(../images/famine.png) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hero-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.hero-container h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  margin: 0;
}

.hero-container h1 span {
  border: 10px solid white;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.des {
  margin: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}

.btn {
  color: #313131;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}
.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

The optimal solution for me would be so when the hamburger menu activates it is not hidden under any of the content of the hero image.

Website before hamburger menu activated: [image: image before hamburger]

Website after hamburger menu activated: [image: image after hamburger]

Comment: You can try adding different z-index , add css of z-index: -1 for the image and z-index: 1 for  the whole div of ham menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, I would recommend you to set the `z-index:` value for your `.menu__box` to something like **99**, so your CSS for the `.menu__box` should look like this:

```css
.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transition-duration: .25s;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

(You can see the `z-index` at the bottom of the above CSS)

This will tell the browser to render your `.menu__box` above everything else on the site. Just make sure that your background image doesn't have a higher `z-index` value than your menu, but that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: hey, the solution did so the menu got above the Hero image as intended, but somehow, the actual buttons that activate and deactive the hamburger menu disappears. d0 i need to set a higher z-index for them again?

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, then I would recommend setting the z-index value for your ' .hamburger-menu navlinks ' to something higher than the z-index you've set for your menu__box (So if the z-index for your menu__box is 99, set the z-index for your 
' hamburger-menu navlinks ' to 100 for example). This will make the hamburger buttons be above your menu. I think that this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try this .

```
.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transition-duration: .25s;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

You can skip hamburger-menu z-index if menu-box z-index works

```
.hamburger-menu {
  z-index:1
}
```

Add lower z-index to image div

```
.hero-image {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(../images/famine.png) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index:-1;

}
```

Try this and tell if it works. Thank you